# PivotTable PageFilter and PivotItem Visibility

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm attempting to set the visibility of PivotItems not shown, when a PageFilter is set to `Visible = False`.

The PivotTable looks as follows:

[image: PivotTable Example]

I'm requiring that any item not present after the PageFilter is set to "1" be hidden from the next portion of my code; which will loop through the (now) visible items present under "Consumable Name".

I've only got as far as this:

```
Dim Pt As PivotTable
Dim Pf As PivotField
Dim Pi As PivotItem

Set Pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set Pf = Pt.PivotFields("Consumable Name")

With Pt
    .PivotCache.Refresh
    .PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
End With

For Each Pi In Pf.VisibleItems
'Do Stuff
```

This currently ignores the PageFilter that has already been placed on the table outside of VBA and simply cycles through all items, that would be in the PivotTable given no Filter.

I think I'm missing the fact, that I haven't assigned PivotItems as visible or not, but not quite sure how to go about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PeterS already mentioned, `PivotItems` are still reported as `Visible` even if you don't see them after filtering the PivotTable.

Quick attempt: You can loop over the `DataRange` of the `PivotField` to get each visible `PivotItem`:

```
Private Sub VisiblePivotItems()
    Dim Pt As PivotTable
    Dim Pf As PivotField
    Dim Pi As PivotItem
    Dim PiCell As Range

    Set Pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTable("PivotTable1")
    Set Pf = Pt.PivotFields("Consumable Name")

    With Pt
        .PivotCache.Refresh
        .PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
    End With

    For Each PiCell In Pf.DataRange.Cells
        If PiCell.Value <> "(blank)" Then
            Set Pi = Pf.PivotItems(PiCell.Value)
            'Do Stuff
        End If
    Next PiCell
End Sub
```

---

Here's another attempt to address all visible PivotItems:

```
' headline items within PivotColumnAxis
Dim i As Long, j As Long
For i = 1 To Pt.PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines.Count
    Select Case Pt.PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(i).LineType
    Case xlPivotLineRegular
        For j = 1 To Pt.PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(i).PivotLineCells.Count
            Set Pf = Pt.PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(i).PivotLineCells(j).PivotField
            Set Pi = Pt.PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(i).PivotLineCells(j).PivotItem
            Debug.Print i, j, Pf.Name, Pi.Name
        Next j
    Case xlPivotLineBlank
         For j = 1 To Pt.PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(i).PivotLineCells.Count
            Set Pf = Pt.PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(i).PivotLineCells(j).PivotField
            Debug.Print i, j, Pf.Name, "(blank)"
        Next j
    Case xlPivotLineSubtotal
         For j = 1 To Pt.PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(i).PivotLineCells.Count
            Set Pf = Pt.PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(i).PivotLineCells(j).PivotField
            Debug.Print i, j, Pf.Name, "Subtotal"
        Next j
    Case xlPivotLineGrandTotal
         For j = 1 To Pt.PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(i).PivotLineCells.Count
            Set Pf = Pt.PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(i).PivotLineCells(j).PivotField
            Debug.Print i, j, Pf.Name, "GrandTotal"
        Next j
   End Select
Next i

' row items within PivotRowAxis
For i = 1 To Pt.PivotRowAxis.PivotLines.Count
    Select Case Pt.PivotRowAxis.PivotLines(i).LineType
    Case xlPivotLineRegular
        For j = 1 To Pt.PivotRowAxis.PivotLines(i).PivotLineCells.Count
            Set Pf = Pt.PivotRowAxis.PivotLines(i).PivotLineCells(j).PivotField
            Set Pi = Pt.PivotRowAxis.PivotLines(i).PivotLineCells(j).PivotItem
            Debug.Print i, j, Pf.Name, Pi.Name
        Next j
    Case xlPivotLineBlank
         For j = 1 To Pt.PivotRowAxis.PivotLines(i).PivotLineCells.Count
            Set Pf = Pt.PivotRowAxis.PivotLines(i).PivotLineCells(j).PivotField
            Debug.Print i, j, Pf.Name, "(blank)"
        Next j
    Case xlPivotLineSubtotal
         For j = 1 To Pt.PivotRowAxis.PivotLines(i).PivotLineCells.Count
            Set Pf = Pt.PivotRowAxis.PivotLines(i).PivotLineCells(j).PivotField
            Debug.Print i, j, Pf.Name, "Subtotal"
        Next j
    Case xlPivotLineGrandTotal
         For j = 1 To Pt.PivotRowAxis.PivotLines(i).PivotLineCells.Count
            Set Pf = Pt.PivotRowAxis.PivotLines(i).PivotLineCells(j).PivotField
            Debug.Print i, j, Pf.Name, "GrandTotal"
        Next j
   End Select
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar posting a week ago here to which I have not received any answer yet: [Excel VBA loop through pivotitems that are filtered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54636850/excel-vba-loop-through-pivotitems-that-are-filtered)
It seems that Page filter setting influences what is visble on the screen, but actually does not chage the Visible property of the pivotitems that are displayed. In my specific case (a very simple pivot table with only one rowfield and a limited number of pivotitems), I took the ugly way by looping through the visible pivotitems (=number of rows based on the position of the pivot table and exluding the Grand Total row), got their names and then used the GetPivotData function for these items only.
Hope this helps.